# Distributions over probability simplex

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, markov-process, transition-matrix

I was wondering if there any probability distributions over the probability simplex ($p \in \mathbb{R^n_+}:\sum_i^n p_i=1,p_i\geq 0$). In particular, what are the distributions which can be used to model transition probabilities of an MDP?

One of the common distributions is Dirichlet distribution. There is also logit-normal distribution. But, are there any other distributions with simple posterior updates especially for categorical observations.

Any suggestions would be really helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked other answers (e.g.: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33685/what-are-some-distributions-over-the-probability-simplex seems relevant).

Comment: @Vimal Yes. But I was unable to find any distribution with a simple (analytic) update rule. Please let me know if I am wrong. Thanks

Comment: The dirichret distribution has reasonably easy posterior updates, as they're all beta-distributed. However, the components are most certainly not independent. Any pair $p_i,p_j$ are negatively correlated, since the sum must be 1.

Comment: @zero if you look at how the linked post parameterises dirichlet into a continuous distribution, you can pick any continuous distribution that has a simple posterior update rule.  There are several on the Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior#Continuous_distributions

Comment: @AlexR. Thanks for pointing it out. I have updated the question.

Comment: @Vimal Yes, that helps a lot. But, I am looking at cases where one the observations could be zero (like in categorical observations) and that transformation cannot be used as we are using geometric mean. Sorry, I didn't mention it before.